# ForwardRef error in Chakra-ui when wrapping IconButton component

Tags: reactjs, chakra-ui

I created a reusable component that wraps the `IconButton` and pass as one of the props icons from `react-icons`.

I get the following error:

> Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access
> this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?`

Here's my component wrapper:

```
export function SidebarMenu({ icon, isActive, handleMenuClick, name }) {
  return (
    <IconButton
      className={isActive ? 'active' : ''}
      aria-label={name + ' menu'}
      isActive={isActive}
      bg="transparent"
      px="0"
      as={icon}
      _hover={{
        cursor: 'pointer',
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
      }}
      _active={{
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
      }}
      onClick={() => handleMenuClick(name)}
    />
```

Here's how i use the wrapper component

```
   <SidebarMenu
    icon={VscCode}
    name="folders"
    handleMenuClick={handleMenuClick}
    isActive={menuList.folders}
   />
```

But if i change the content `IconButton` to a instead use a `Icon` wrapped in a `Button` the error disappears.

```
export function SidebarMenu({ icon, isActive, handleMenuClick, name }) {
  return (
    <Button
      className={isActive ? 'active' : ''}
      aria-label={name + ' menu'}
      isActive={isActive}
      bg="transparent"
      px="0"
      // as={icon}
      _hover={{
        cursor: 'pointer',
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
      }}
      _active={{
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
      }}
      onClick={() => handleMenuClick(name)}
    >
      <Icon as={icon} w={7} h={7} />
    </Button>
  );
}
```

**Edit:**
For anyone who may stumble on the same problem.
There are couple of things i did wrong here.

1. I was using `as` instead of `icon` prop in `IconButton`
2. Second, i was passing a reference instead of the component
   Instead of doing `<IconButton icon={<VsColorMode />} />`, i was doing this `<IconButton icon={VsCodeMode} />`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the doc, [`IconButton`](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/components/form/icon-button#props) has its own prop `icon`, so instead of using `as`, in this case, use `icon` with `Icon`

```
function SidebarMenu({ icon }) {
  return (
    <IconButton
      bg="transparent"
      px="0"
      icon={<Icon as={icon} w={7} h={7} />}
      // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      _hover={{
        cursor: "pointer",
        backgroundColor: "transparent"
      }}
      _active={{
        backgroundColor: "transparent"
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

Codesandbox demo

[image: Edit laughing-rain-43jfhl]

Comment: Awesome, this did the trick. I overlooked that property.